# How to use jQuery UI with Parcel

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui, parceljs

I'm trying to use jQuery UI features in a react app widget that I am bundling with Parcel. The app works with UI features like draggable in development using yarn start but I get an error when adding the Parcel output to a demo page.

I'm including jquery & jquery UI like this:

```
// Item.js
import "./../import-jquery";
import $ from "jquery";

import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/resizable';
import 'jquery-ui-rotatable';

//import-jquery.js
import jquery from "jquery";
export default (window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery);
```

This gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.ui is undefined
```

How can I include jquery-ui properly with Parcel so that it works as it does in the dev environment?

The line given in console for the error is:

```
var t;!function(e){"function"==typeof t&&t.amd?t(["jquery","./mouse","../data","../plugin","../safe-active-element","../safe-blur","../scroll-parent","../version","../widget"],e):e(jQuery)}(function(t){return t.widget("ui.draggable",t.ui.mouse,{version:"1.12.1",widgetEventPrefix:"drag",options:{addClasses:!0,appendTo:"parent",axis:!1,connectToSortable:!1,containment:!1,cursor:"auto",cursorAt:!1,grid:!1,handle:!1,helper:"original",iframeFix:!1,opacity:!1,refreshPositions:!1,revert:!1,revertDuration:500,scope:"default",scroll:!0,scrollSensitivity:20,scrollSpeed:20,snap:!1,snapMode:"both",snapTolerance:20,stack:!1,zIndex:!1,drag:null,start:null,stop:null},_create:function(){"original"===this.options.helper&&this._setPositionRelative(),this.options.addClasses&&this._addClass("ui-draggable"),this._setHandleClassName(),this._mouseInit()},_setOption:function(t,e){this._super(t,e),"handle"===t&&(this._removeHandleClassName(),this._setHandleClassName())},_destroy:function(){(this.helper||this.element).is(".ui-draggable-dragging")?this.destroyOnClear=!0:(this._removeHandleClassName(),this._mouseDestroy())},_mouseCapture:function(e){var s=this.options;return!(this.helper||s.disabled||t(e.target).closest(".ui-resizable-handle").length>0)&&(this.handle=this._getHandle(e),!!this.handle&&(this._blurActiveElement(e),this._blockFrames(!0===s.iframeFix?"iframe":s.iframeFix),!0))},_blockFrames:function(e){this.iframeBlocks=this.document.find(e).map(function(){var e=t(this);return t("<div>").css("position","absolute").appendTo(e.parent()).outerWidth(e.outerWidth()).outerHeight(e.outerHeight()).offset(e.offset())[0]})},_unblockFrames:function(){this.iframeBlocks&&(this.iframeBlocks.remove(),delete this.iframeBlocks)},_blurActiveElement:function(e){var s=t.ui.safeActiveElement(this.document[0]);t(e.target).closest(s).length||t.ui.safeBlur(s)},_mouseStart:function(e){var s=this.options;return this.helper=this._createHelper(e),this._addClass(this.helper,"ui-draggable-dragging"),this._cacheHelperProportions(),t.ui.ddmanager&&(t.ui.ddmanager.current=this),this._cacheMargins(),this.cssPosition=this.helper.css("position"),this.scrollParent=this.helper.scrollParent(!0),this.offsetParent=this.helper.offsetParent(),this.hasFixedAncestor=this.helper.parents().filter(function(){return"fixed"===t(this).css("position")}).length>0,this.positionAbs=this.element.offset(),this._refreshOffsets(e),this.originalPosition=this.position=this._generatePosition(e,!1),this.originalPageX=e.pageX,this.originalPageY=e.pageY,s.cursorAt&&this._adjustOffsetFromHelper(s.cursorAt),this._setContainment(),!1===this._trigger("start",e)?(this._clear(),!1):(this._cacheHelperProportions(),t.ui.ddmanager&&!s.dropBehaviour&&t.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(this,e),this._mouseDrag(e,!0),t.ui.ddmanager&&t.ui.ddmanager.dragStart(this,e),!0)},_refreshOffsets:function(t){this.offset={top:this.positionAbs.top-this.margins.top,left:this.positionAbs.left-this.margins.left,scroll:!1,parent:this._getParentOffset(),relative:this._getRelativeOffset()},this.offset.click={left:t.pageX-this.offset.left,top:t.pageY-this.offset.top}},_mouseDrag:function(e,s){if(this.hasFixedAncestor&&(this.offset.parent=this._getParentOffset()),this.position=this._generatePosition(e,!0),this.positionAbs=this._convertPositionTo("absolute"),!s){var i=this._uiHash();if(!1===this._trigger("drag",e,i))return this._mouseUp(new t.Event("mouseup",e)),!1;this.position=i.position}return this.helper[0].style.left=this.position.left+"px",this.helper[0].style.top=this.position.top+"px",t.ui.ddmanager&&t.ui.ddmanager.drag(this,e),!1},_mouseStop:function(e){var s=this,i=!1;return t.ui.ddmanager&&!this.options.dropBehaviour&&(i=t.ui.ddmanager.drop(this,e)),this.dropped&&(i=this.dropped,this.dropped=!1),"invalid"===this.options.revert&&!i||"valid"===this.options.revert&&i||!0===this.options.revert||t.isFunction(this.options.revert)&&this.options.revert.call(this.element,i)?t(this.helper).animate(this.originalPosition,parseInt(this.options.revertDuration,10),function(){!1!==s._trigger("stop",e)&&s._clear()}):!1!==this._trigger("stop",e)&&this._clear(),!1},_mouseUp:function(e){return this._unblockFrames(),t.ui.ddmanager&&t.ui.ddmanager.dragStop(this,e),this.handleElement.is(e.target)&&this.element.trigger("focus"),t.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseUp.call(this,e)},cancel:function(){return this.helper.is(".ui-draggable-dragging")?this._mouseUp(new t.Event("mouseup",{target:this.element[0]})):this._clear(),this},_getHandle:function(e){return!this.options.handle||!!t(e.target).closest(this.element.find(this.options.handle)).length},_setHandleClassName:function(){this.handleElement=this.options.handle?this.element.find(this.options.handle):this.element,this._addClass(this.handleElement,"ui-draggable-handle")},_removeHandleClassName:function(){this._removeClass(this.handleElement,"ui-draggable-handle")},_createHelper:function(e){var s=this.options,i=t.isFunction(s.helper),o=i?t(s.helper.apply(this.element[0],[e])):"clone"===s.helper?this.element.clone().removeAttr("id"):this.element;return o.parents("body").length||o.appendTo("parent"===s.appendTo?this.element[0].parentNode:s.appendTo),i&&o[0]===this.element[0]&&this._setPositionRelative(),o[0]===this.element[0]||/(fixed|absolute)/.test(o.css("position"))||o.css("position","absolute"),o},_setPositionRelative:function(){/^(?:r|a|f)/.test(this.element.css("position"))||(this.element[0].style.position="relative")},_adjustOffsetFromHelper:function(e){"string"==typeof e&&(e=e.split(" ")),t.isArray(e)&&(e={left:+e[0],top:+e[1]||0}),"left"in e&&(this.offset.click.left=e.left+this.margins.left),"right"in e&&(this.offset.click.left=this.helperProportions.width-e.right+this.margins.left),"top"in e&&(this.offset.click.top=e.top+this.margins.top),"bottom"in e&&(this.offset.click.top=this.helperProportions.height-e.bottom+this.margins.top)},_isRootNode:function(t){return/(html|body)/i.test(t.tagName)||t===this.document[0]},_getParentOffset:function(){var e=this.offsetParent.offset(),s=this.document[0];return"absolute"===this.cssPosition&&this.scrollParent[0]!==s&&t.contains(this.scrollParent[0],this.offsetParent[0])&&(e.left+=this.scrollParent.scrollLeft(),e.top+=this.scrollParent.scrollTop()),this._isRootNode(this.offsetParent[0])&&(e={top:0,left:0}),{top:e.top+(parseInt(this.offsetParent.css("borderTopWidth"),10)||0),left:e.left+(parseInt(this.offsetParent.css("borderLeftWidth"),10)||0)}},_getRelativeOffset:function(){if("relative"!==this.cssPosition)return{top:0,left:0};var t=this.element.position(),e=this._isRootNode(this.scrollParent[0]);return{top:t.top-(parseInt(this.helper.css("top"),10)||0)+(e?0:this.scrollParent.scrollTop()),left:t.left-(parseInt(this.helper.css("left"),10)||0)+(e?0:this.scrollParent.scrollLeft())}},_cacheMargins:function(){this.margins={left:parseInt(this.element.css("marginLeft"),10)||0,top:parseInt(this.element.css("marginTop"),10)||0,right:parseInt(this.element.css("marginRight"),10)||0,bottom:parseInt(this.element.css("marginBottom"),10)||0}},_cacheHelperProportions:function(){this.helperProportions={width:this.helper.outerWidth(),height:this.helper.outerHeight()}},_setContainment:function(){var e,s,i,o=this.options,n=this.document[0];this.relativeContainer=null,o.containment?"window"!==o.containment?"document"!==o.containment?o.containment.constructor!==Array?("parent"===o.containment&&(o.containment=this.helper[0].parentNode),(i=(s=t(o.containment))[0])&&(e=/(scroll|auto)/.test(s.css("overflow")),this.containment=[(parseInt(s.css("borderLeftWidth"),10)||0)+(parseInt(s.css("paddingLeft"),10)||0),(parseInt(s.css("borderTopWidth"),10)||0)+(parseInt(s.css("paddingTop"),10)||0),(e?Math.max(i.scrollWidth,i.offsetWidth):i.offsetWidth)-(parseInt(s.css("borderRightWidth"),10)||0)-(parseInt(s.css("paddingRight"),10)||0)-this.helperProportions.width-this.margins.left-this.margins.right,(e?Math.max(i.scrollHeight,i.offsetHeight):i.offsetHeight)-(parseInt(s.css("borderBottomWidth"),10)||0)-(parseInt(s.css("paddingBottom"),10)||0)-this.helperProportions.height-this.margins.top-this.margins.bottom],this.relativeContainer=s)):this.containment=o.containment:this.containment=[0,0,t(n).width()-this.helperProportions.width-this.margins.left,(t(n).height()||n.body.parentNode.scrollHeight)-this.helperProportions.height-this.margins.top]:this.containment=[t(window).scrollLeft()-this.offset.relative.left-this.offset.parent.left,t(window).scrollTop()-this.offset.relative.top-this.offset.parent.top,t(window).scrollLeft()+t(window).width()-this.helperProportions.width-this.margins.left,t(window).scrollTop()+(t(window).height()||n.body.parentNode.scrollHeight)-this.helperProportions.height-this.margins.top]:this.containment=null},_convertPositionTo:function(t,e){e||(e=this.position);var s="absolute"===t?1:-1,i=this._isRootNode(this.scrollParent[0]);return{top:e.top+this.offset.relative.top*s+this.offset.parent.top*s-("fixed"===this.cssPosition?-this.offset.scroll.top:i?0:this.offset.scroll.top)*s,left:e.left+this.offset.relative.left*s+this.offset.parent.left*s-("fixed"===this.cssPosition?-this.offset.scroll.left:i?0:this.offset.scroll.left)*s}},_generatePosition:function(t,e){var s,i,o,n,r=this.options,l=this._isRootNode(this.scrollParent[0]),a=t.pageX,h=t.pageY;return l&&this.offset.scroll||(this.offset.scroll={top:this.scrollParent.scrollTop(),left:this.scrollParent.scrollLeft()}),e&&(this.containment&&(this.relativeContainer?(i=this.relativeContainer.offset(),s=[this.containment[0]+i.left,this.containment[1]+i.top,this.containment[2]+i.left,this.containment[3]+i.top]):s=this.containment,t.pageX-this.offset.click.left<s[0]&&(a=s[0]+this.offset.click.left),t.pageY-this.offset.click.top<s[1]&&(h=s[1]+this.offset.click.top),t.pageX-this.offset.click.left>s[2]&&(a=s[2]+this.offset.click.left),t.pageY-this.offset.click.top>s[3]&&(h=s[3]+this.offset.click.top)),r.grid&&(o=r.grid[1]?this.originalPageY+Math.round((h-this.originalPageY)/r.grid[1])*r.grid[1]:this.originalPageY,h=s?o-this.offset.click.top>=s[1]||o-this.offset.click.top>s[3]?o:o-this.offset.click.top>=s[1]?o-r.grid[1]:o+r.grid[1]:o,n=r.grid[0]?this.originalPageX+Math.round((a-this.originalPageX)/r.grid[0])*r.grid[0]:this.originalPageX,a=s?n-this.offset.click.left>=s[0]||n-this.offset.click.left>s[2]?n:n-this.offset.click.left>=s[0]?n-r.grid[0]:n+r.grid[0]:n),"y"===r.axis&&(a=this.originalPageX),"x"===r.axis&&(h=this.originalPageY)),{top:h-this.offset.click.top-this.offset.relative.top-this.offset.parent.top+("fixed"===this.cssPosition?-this.offset.scroll.top:l?0:this.offset.scroll.top),left:a-this.offset.click.left-this.offset.relative.left-this.offset.parent.left+("fixed"===this.cssPosition?-this.offset.scroll.left:l?0:this.offset.scroll.left)}},_clear:function(){this._removeClass(this.helper,"ui-draggable-dragging"),this.helper[0]===this.element[0]||this.cancelHelperRemoval||this.helper.remove(),this.helper=null,this.cancelHelperRemoval=!1,this.destroyOnClear&&this.destroy()},_trigger:function(e,s,i){return i=i||this._uiHash(),t.ui.plugin.call(this,e,[s,i,this],!0),/^(drag|start|stop)/.test(e)&&(this.positionAbs=this._convertPositionTo("absolute"),i.offset=this.positionAbs),t.Widget.prototype._trigger.call(this,e,s,i)},plugins:{},_uiHash:function(){return{helper:this.helper,position:this.position,originalPosition:this.originalPosition,offset:this.positionAbs}}}),t.ui.plugin.add("draggable","connectToSortable",{start:function(e,s,i){var o=t.extend({},s,{item:i.element});i.sortables=[],t(i.options.connectToSortable).each(function(){var s=t(this).sortable("instance");s&&!s.options.disabled&&(i.sortables.push(s),s.refreshPositions(),s._trigger("activate",e,o))})},stop:function(e,s,i){var o=t.extend({},s,{item:i.element});i.cancelHelperRemoval=!1,t.each(i.sortables,function(){this.isOver?(this.isOver=0,i.cancelHelperRemoval=!0,this.cancelHelperRemoval=!1,this._storedCSS={position:this.placeholder.css("position"),top:this.placeholder.css("top"),left:this.placeholder.css("left")},this._mouseStop(e),this.options.helper=this.options._helper):(this.cancelHelperRemoval=!0,this._trigger("deactivate",e,o))})},drag:function(e,s,i){t.each(i.sortables,function(){var o=!1,n=this;n.positionAbs=i.positionAbs,n.helperProportions=i.helperProportions,n.offset.click=i.offset.click,n._intersectsWith(n.containerCache)&&(o=!0,t.each(i.sortables,function(){return this.positionAbs=i.positionAbs,this.helperProportions=i.helperProportions,this.offset.click=i.offset.click,this!==n&&this._intersectsWith(this.containerCache)&&t.contains(n.element[0],this.element[0])&&(o=!1),o})),o?(n.isOver||(n.isOver=1,i._parent=s.helper.parent(),n.currentItem=s.helper.appendTo(n.element).data("ui-sortable-item",!0),n.options._helper=n.options.helper,n.options.helper=function(){return s.helper[0]},e.target=n.currentItem[0],n._mouseCapture(e,!0),n._mouseStart(e,!0,!0),n.offset.click.top=i.offset.click.top,n.offset.click.left=i.offset.click.left,n.offset.parent.left-=i.offset.parent.left-n.offset.parent.left,n.offset.parent.top-=i.offset.parent.top-n.offset.parent.top,i._trigger("toSortable",e),i.dropped=n.element,t.each(i.sortables,function(){this.refreshPositions()}),i.currentItem=i.element,n.fromOutside=i),n.currentItem&&(n._mouseDrag(e),s.position=n.position)):n.isOver&&(n.isOver=0,n.cancelHelperRemoval=!0,n.options._revert=n.options.revert,n.options.revert=!1,n._trigger("out",e,n._uiHash(n)),n._mouseStop(e,!0),n.options.revert=n.options._revert,n.options.helper=n.options._helper,n.placeholder&&n.placeholder.remove(),s.helper.appendTo(i._parent),i._refreshOffsets(e),s.position=i._generatePosition(e,!0),i._trigger("fromSortable",e),i.dropped=!1,t.each(i.sortables,function(){this.refreshPositions()}))})}}),t.ui.plugin.add("draggable","cursor",{start:function(e,s,i){var o=t("body"),n=i.options;o.css("cursor")&&(n._cursor=o.css("cursor")),o.css("cursor",n.cursor)},stop:function(e,s,i){var o=i.options;o._cursor&&t("body").css("cursor",o._cursor)}}),t.ui.plugin.add("draggable","opacity",{start:function(e,s,i){var o=t(s.helper),n=i.options;o.css("opacity")&&(n._opacity=o.css("opacity")),o.css("opacity",n.opacity)},stop:function(e,s,i){var o=i.options;o._opacity&&t(s.helper).css("opacity",o._opacity)}}),t.ui.plugin.add("draggable","scroll",{start:function(t,e,s){s.scrollParentNotHidden||(s.scrollParentNotHidden=s.helper.scrollParent(!1)),s.scrollParentNotHidden[0]!==s.document[0]&&"HTML"!==s.scrollParentNotHidden[0].tagName&&(s.overflowOffset=s.scrollParentNotHidden.offset())},drag:function(e,s,i){var o=i.options,n=!1,r=i.scrollParentNotHidden[0],l=i.document[0];r!==l&&"HTML"!==r.tagName?(o.axis&&"x"===o.axis||(i.overflowOffset.top+r.offsetHeight-e.pageY<o.scrollSensitivity?r.scrollTop=n=r.scrollTop+o.scrollSpeed:e.pageY-i.overflowOffset.top<o.scrollSensitivity&&(r.scrollTop=n=r.scrollTop-o.scrollSpeed)),o.axis&&"y"===o.axis||(i.overflowOffset.left+r.offsetWidth-e.pageX<o.scrollSensitivity?r.scrollLeft=n=r.scrollLeft+o.scrollSpeed:e.pageX-i.overflowOffset.left<o.scrollSensitivity&&(r.scrollLeft=n=r.scrollLeft-o.scrollSpeed))):(o.axis&&"x"===o.axis||(e.pageY-t(l).scrollTop()<o.scrollSensitivity?n=t(l).scrollTop(t(l).scrollTop()-o.scrollSpeed):t(window).height()-(e.pageY-t(l).scrollTop())<o.scrollSensitivity&&(n=t(l).scrollTop(t(l).scrollTop()+o.scrollSpeed))),o.axis&&"y"===o.axis||(e.pageX-t(l).scrollLeft()<o.scrollSensitivity?n=t(l).scrollLeft(t(l).scrollLeft()-o.scrollSpeed):t(window).width()-(e.pageX-t(l).scrollLeft())<o.scrollSensitivity&&(n=t(l).scrollLeft(t(l).scrollLeft()+o.scrollSpeed)))),!1!==n&&t.ui.ddmanager&&!o.dropBehaviour&&t.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(i,e)}}),t.ui.plugin.add("draggable","snap",{start:function(e,s,i){var o=i.options;i.snapElements=[],t(o.snap.constructor!==String?o.snap.items||":data(ui-draggable)":o.snap).each(function(){var e=t(this),s=e.offset();this!==i.element[0]&&i.snapElements.push({item:this,width:e.outerWidth(),height:e.outerHeight(),top:s.top,left:s.left})})},drag:function(e,s,i){var o,n,r,l,a,h,p,c,f,d,g=i.options,u=g.snapTolerance,m=s.offset.left,v=m+i.helperProportions.width,_=s.offset.top,P=_+i.helperProportions.height;for(f=i.snapElements.length-1;f>=0;f--)h=(a=i.snapElements[f].left-i.margins.left)+i.snapElements[f].width,c=(p=i.snapElements[f].top-i.margins.top)+i.snapElements[f].height,v<a-u||m>h+u||P<p-u||_>c+u||!t.contains(i.snapElements[f].item.ownerDocument,i.snapElements[f].item)?(i.snapElements[f].snapping&&i.options.snap.release&&i.options.snap.release.call(i.element,e,t.extend(i._uiHash(),{snapItem:i.snapElements[f].item})),i.snapElements[f].snapping=!1):("inner"!==g.snapMode&&(o=Math.abs(p-P)<=u,n=Math.abs(c-_)<=u,r=Math.abs(a-v)<=u,l=Math.abs(h-m)<=u,o&&(s.position.top=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:p-i.helperProportions.height,left:0}).top),n&&(s.position.top=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:c,left:0}).top),r&&(s.position.left=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:0,left:a-i.helperProportions.width}).left),l&&(s.position.left=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:0,left:h}).left)),d=o||n||r||l,"outer"!==g.snapMode&&(o=Math.abs(p-_)<=u,n=Math.abs(c-P)<=u,r=Math.abs(a-m)<=u,l=Math.abs(h-v)<=u,o&&(s.position.top=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:p,left:0}).top),n&&(s.position.top=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:c-i.helperProportions.height,left:0}).top),r&&(s.position.left=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:0,left:a}).left),l&&(s.position.left=i._convertPositionTo("relative",{top:0,left:h-i.helperProportions.width}).left)),!i.snapElements[f].snapping&&(o||n||r||l||d)&&i.options.snap.snap&&i.options.snap.snap.call(i.element,e,t.extend(i._uiHash(),{snapItem:i.snapElements[f].item})),i.snapElements[f].snapping=o||n||r||l||d)}}),t.ui.plugin.add("draggable","stack",{start:function(e,s,i){var o,n=i.options,r=t.makeArray(t(n.stack)).sort(function(e,s){return(parseInt(t(e).css("zIndex"),10)||0)-(parseInt(t(s).css("zIndex"),10)||0)});r.length&&(o=parseInt(t(r[0]).css("zIndex"),10)||0,t(r).each(function(e){t(this).css("zIndex",o+e)}),this.css("zIndex",o+r.length))}}),t.ui.plugin.add("draggable","zIndex",{start:function(e,s,i){var o=t(s.helper),n=i.options;o.css("zIndex")&&(n._zIndex=o.css("zIndex")),o.css("zIndex",n.zIndex)},stop:function(e,s,i){var o=i.options;o._zIndex&&t(s.helper).css("zIndex",o._zIndex)}}),t.ui.draggable});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use jquery-ui-dist instead of the individual items.

yarn add jquery-ui-dist

and then

```
// Item.js
import "./../import-jquery";
import $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js";
```